# Why NMSE is the same as output SNR but with an opposite sign?

Tags: signal-analysis, wavelet, denoising, performance

I am doing denoising on signal, and as performance measures Normalized Mean Squared Error (NMSE) and output-SNR between original/clean and denoised signals are used.
However, for several cases the answer for NMSE and oSNR are the same but with different signs. Is it okay?

Input SNR for clean signal = 15 dB
O-SNR = 19.166491 dB
NMSE = -19.166491 dB

Answer (score 0):

I mean, for fixed signal power, SNR is proportional to the inverse of noise power, and NMSE is literally the normalized inverse noise power. In decibel, inverse is just a sign change.

Comment: then using both SNR and NMSE is not logical? So I should choose either SNR or NMSE, right?

Comment: if you've got constant signal power at the receiver, it's equivalent. If not, it's different things.